# Possibility of a personal server

Tags: web, cloud-storage, web-server

I am curious as to the possibility of creating a personal server which can store basic data, such as passwords, a todo list, shopping list, maybe even a calendar for sceduling. I would like the information to be accessable as long as I have internet (ie through a very basic website) which would allow for me to access from a pc or my phone. I would also love to be able to display info on a smart mirror (ie. todo list or shopping list).

Is there any software out there that potentially does this already or could assist? I understand services such as google drive are avaliable but this is more of a personal project I want to work on and learn from over a long period of time, as well as keep my information completely private.

Any help is really appreciated. Im not very fluent with coding and web/server dev however as I said I would like to take this opportunity to learn (if possible).

Kind regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plenty. Most famous one would be **[Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/).** I'm running that for years, and am very satisfied with it. Coming with "core functionality" like file storage, calendar and contacts, it has addons (called "[Nextcloud Apps](https://apps.nextcloud.com/)" for quite a lot of use cases – including your todo list ([Tasks](https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/tasks)), a password manager ([Passwords](https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/passwords), [Passman](https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/passman)), and many more.

*Nextcloud* requires a server with PHP (at least PHP 7.2 for recent versions), comes free of charge, is open source, well supported, and has a huge community – so it shouldn't be that hard to find help when needed.

Comment: And this could be done on either a home ISP with a static IP, or a cloud-hosted virtual on a service like Digital Ocean.

Comment: Yes. I'm using it behind a dynamic IP, the name being resolved by a DynDNS entry. Beind a static it should be no issue at all (one of my instances has that). Can run on a sub-domain dedicated to it, or in a sub-directory of an existing web server.

Comment: PS: you can even sync it with other devices. Here I eg use DAVx5 to sync calendar/addressbook with my Android devices, on the desktop my PIM app does the same, even my landline phone accesses the addressbook via WebDAV. Same goes for files (well, without the landline :D), tasks, and so on. Of course, all Nextcloud features are accessible via web browser, too.